# Tinymce and predefined pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Is there a way to place already uploaded pictures into the "insert image"-Section of a tinymce textarea?

Just found a way to generate a button next to the image-url field which places a predefined URL with alternative text. My full JavaScript for this would look like that:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 350,
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "media table contextmenu paste imagetools"
            ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        image_caption: true,
        file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
            // Provide file and text for the link dialog
            if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
            callback('mypage.html', {text: 'My text'});
            }

            // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
            if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
            callback('myimage.jpg', {alt: 'My alt text'});
            }

            // Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog
            if (meta.filetype == 'media') {
            callback('movie.mp4', {source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'image.jpg'});
            }
        }
        });
    </script>
```

With this method, just one picture is possible but I want to add a bunch of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on my own :)

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_list